# how to write two solr queries second query result is based on first query?

Tags: search, solr, solrj

I want to write `one solr query` which basically takes two solr queries. The second query result is dependent on first query.

Let's say in first query I am faceting `Locality` specific data. If the results are zero, I want to facet based on sub Locality data.

Comment: And where would your conditional logic live in? If between the queries, you have to do Custom something anyway.

Comment: i just want to know is there any specific query we can fire to solr ?

Comment: you can do this in the application level, fire the first query, if no results, then fire 2nd query. That's the easier approach.

Comment: but i have to do two times opening and closing connections right? i want to aviod it.

Comment: It depends, any established solr libraries will make use of the existing connection. Virtually, this isn't an issue. And you only need the second query when the first query is not result.